How to config Helix editor to support suggestions in comments/strings
Suppose I have the code
// todo implement fooFunction
const foo

When I type "const foo", I want Helix to suggest "fooFunction" because the text "fooFunction" exists elsewhere. How can I achieve that in Helix? (I can do that in VS Code.)

I found the answer (via reddit)
https://github.com/estin/simple-completion-language-server is the best way for now
